# Is there a cleaner way to chain filters with the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been doing this:

```
Model.objects.filter(key1=value1)\
             .exclude(key2=value2)\
             .order_by('key3')\
             .select_related(depth=1)
```

but am hating the `\`. Is there a cleaner style?

Comment: this is related to python more than django...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, you can take advantage of the fact that Django QuerySet operations are cumulative, and lazy:

```
 myobjects = Model.objects.filter(key1=value1)
 myobjects = myobjects.exclude(key2=value2)
 myobjects = myobjects.order_by('key3')
 myobjects = myobjects.select_related(depth=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Parens will prevent Python from breaking it up until closed.

```
(
  Model.objects.filter(key1=value1)
               .exclude(key2=value2)
               .order_by('key3')
               .select_related(depth=1)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Ignacio said, but you can also close the parens on the next line instead of wrapping the whole thing.

```
Model.objects.filter(key1=value1
              ).exclude(key2=value2
              ).order_by('key3'
              ).select_related(depth=1)
```